# HealthKit may be giving incomplete data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

Has anyone had the problem that HealthKit seems to give incomplete data? With the following query:

```
HKAnchoredObjectQuery *newQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:quantityType predicate:predicate anchor:anchor limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable sampleObjects, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * _Nullable deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable newAnchor, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                /*...etc...*/
            }];
```

I sometimes see only part of the data rather than all of it. Also, there's no pattern to which of the data I see (it's chunks, not like I see all the most recent or all the earliest). **Has anyone else encountered this?**

Here's my exact code:

```
- (void) getAllStoredDataForHKQuantityIdentifier:(NSString *)theHKIdentifier withCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *results))completion startingFromAnchor: (HKQueryAnchor *)anchor {

    HKQuantityType *quantityType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:theHKIdentifier];

    HKSourceQuery *sourceQuery = [[HKSourceQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:quantityType samplePredicate:nil completionHandler:^(HKSourceQuery *query, NSSet *sources, NSError *error) {
        if( error ) {
            completion(nil);
            return;
        }

        NSMutableSet *sourcesNo = [NSMutableSet new];
        for( HKSource *thisSource in sources ) {
            if( ![thisSource.bundleIdentifier isEqualToString:@"my.appname.app"] ) {
                [sourcesNo addObject:thisSource];
            }
        }

        for(HKSource* useSource in sourcesNo){

            NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSources:[NSSet setWithObject:useSource]];

            HKAnchoredObjectQuery *newQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:quantityType predicate:predicate anchor:anchor limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray<__kindof HKSample *> * _Nullable sampleObjects, NSArray<HKDeletedObject *> * _Nullable deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor * _Nullable newAnchor, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                completion(sampleObjects);
            }];

            [healthStore executeQuery:newQuery];
        }
    }];

    [healthStore executeQuery:sourceQuery];
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the results you're seeing and what you expect to see instead?  What is the quantity type and predicate you are using?  How many results do you get?  Is there anything interesting logged in the console output?

Comment: @Allan I am trying to load a long list of user's glucose reading from another app. I get some but not all of the readings, and there's no pattern to which readings I get (it's not a chronology issue).

Comment: It would still be useful see how your predicate is constructed and whether anything is logged in Console.

Comment: @Allan I've posted the exact code. Thanks for any ideas you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the same anchor for all the `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` instances you execute.  They have distinct predicates, so the results won't make sense if you reuse a single anchor.  There are a few ways to achieve what you are attempting to do in this code snippet without executing multiple queries.   As I mentioned in the answer to your other question, I'd suggest you just use a single `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` and then processing the results by looking at the `source` property of the `HKSamples` you get back.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot find any detailed documentation as to exactly what an anchor is as returned by the query callback. Where is this documentation?

Comment: Have you read this?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKAnchoredObjectQuery_Class/index.html#

Comment: You are not meant to interpret the value of HKQueryAnchor - it is an opaque reference to what HealthKit uses internally.  You should simply save the anchor that is returned when the query returns results and then provide the saved anchor the next time you execute the same query with the same predicate.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, but can you point to where this is specified in the docs? It's such an opaque class type that it's opaque as to how to use it properly.

Comment: I don't think there is documentation that goes into more detail than that.  What part of using an anchor do you feel unsure about?

Comment: BTW you can store HKQueryAnchors to disk if you need - they support Coding (it you then look into it after it's been coded then it's just an integer under the hood, but you shouldn't assume that in your code; previous versions of iOS even allowed to do [HKQueryAnchor init: {some NSInteger}], but this initializer is deprecated now)

Answer (score 0):

Also, it can be pretty dangerous to use HKObjectQueryNoLimit with HKAnchoredObjectQuery and types like Active Energy. At least on older iPhones, our tests has shown that in some cases some of our users had some odd structure of those Active Energy HKSamples inside their HealthKit database apparently, so that they had like 1 million of those samples in a range of 100 days. And in those cases HKAnchoredObjectQuery would just stuck inside and never return to its completion hander whatsoever... Maybe this was a bug on those early iOS-es and now it's fixed, but you never know - it was reproducible like in 100 cases out of our 300 thousand users base. We solved that by using 100.000 samples limit instead of no-limit, and then making those anchored queries recursively if the limit isn't reached